# insert multiple rows to mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i am trying to insert multiple rows to mysql but it only sends last row. 
i am using javascript to create rows dynamically but it is sending only the last row
this is my form file code
index.php

```
<style type="text/css">
table,tr,td{border:0px solid black;}
</style>
  <table id="titlebar" cellspacing="0px">
        <tr>
            <td style="width:20px;">&#10003;</td>
            <td style="width:160px;">Show</td>
            <td style="width:62px;">season</td>
            <td style="width:63px;">episode</td>
            <td style="width:100px;">language</td>
            <td style="width:190px;">Link 1</td>
            <td style="width:190px;">Link 2</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <form action="send.php" method="POST">
  <table id="dataTable" width="auto" style="margin:-4px 0 0 0;" cellspacing="0px">
    <tr>
      <td style="width:20px;"><INPUT type="checkbox" name="chk" /></td>
      <td><INPUT type="text" name="series" style="width:160px;" autocomplete="on" placeholder="Show" required/></td>
            <td><INPUT type="text" name="season" style="width:62px;" autocomplete="on" placeholder="season" required/></td>
            <td><INPUT type="text" name="episode" style="width:63px;" autocomplete="on" placeholder="episode" required/></td>
      <td>
        <SELECT name="language" style="width:100px;">
          <OPTION value="one">one</OPTION>
          <OPTION value="two">two</OPTION>
          <OPTION value="three">three</OPTION>
          <OPTION value="four">four</OPTION>
          <OPTION value="five">five</OPTION>
          <OPTION value="six">six</OPTION>
          <OPTION value="seven">seven</OPTION>
        </SELECT>
      </td>
            <td><INPUT type="text" name="link_1" style="width:190px;" autocomplete="on" placeholder="link 1" required/></td>
            <td><INPUT type="text" name="link_2" style="width:190px;" autocomplete="on" placeholder="link 2" required/></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
    <INPUT type="button" value="Add row" onclick="addRow('dataTable')" />
  <INPUT type="button" value="Delete row" onclick="deleteRow('dataTable')" />
    <INPUT type="submit" value="Send"/>
    </form>


<script language="Javascript">  
    function addRow(tableID) {
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
    var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;
    for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {
        var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
        newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
        //alert(newcell.childNodes);
        switch(newcell.childNodes[0].type) {
            case "text":
                newcell.childNodes[0].value = "";
                break;
            case "text":
                newcell.childNodes[0].value = "";
                break;
            case "text":
                newcell.childNodes[0].value = "";
                break;
            case "text":
                newcell.childNodes[0].value = "";
                break;
            case "text":
                newcell.childNodes[0].value = "";
                break;
            case "checkbox":
                newcell.childNodes[0].checked = false;
                break;
            case "select-one":
                newcell.childNodes[0].selectedIndex = 0;
                break;
        }
    }
}
function deleteRow(tableID) {
    try {
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) {
        var row = table.rows[i];
        var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
        if(null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
            if(rowCount <= 1) {
                alert("Cant delete all rows");
                break;
            }
            table.deleteRow(i);
            rowCount--;
            i--;
        }
    }
    }catch(e) {
        alert(e);
    }
}
</script>
```

and this my post code

send.php

```
<?php
include('mysql.php');
$seriesV = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['series']));
$seasonV = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['season']));
$episodeV = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['episode']));
$languageV = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['language']));
$link_1V = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['link_1']));
$link_2V = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['link_2']));
$sql="INSERT INTO 0_stock_master (stock_id,category_id,tax_type_id,description,long_description,sales_account,cogs_account)
 VALUES
 ('$seriesV','$seasonV','$episodeV','$languageV','$link_1V','$link_2V','".time()."')";
if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
 {
 die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
 }
 echo "1 record added";
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Please help to submit all the rows in mysql database.

Comment: If you have HTML input name same for two textboxes or checkboxes, then in post at php side, you will always gets last one. So in your case, either make different HTML input name for each one or use input array.

Comment: i am not getting you can you explain or tell me the solution

Comment: Can you paste `var_dump($_POST)` ?

Comment: no i have never used this

Answer (score 0):

first change the names of your dynamically created elements.
next you could walk though the entire post data with:
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) 
    { 
        //... get your row values and execute sql 
    }